# Excel and Sharepoint integration

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I can't really find a clear answer or solution for my problem.

What I have is the following: An excel file where a user inputs data in a UserForm and that data is then added to a table in this same excel file. Multiple users will get such an excel file so that they can add data on their own.

What I want to do is to aggregate this data in my own Excel file. Or Sharepoint List. I don't really prefer any option as both would work for me.

The user excel file is done and works. All that is left to do is to send the data in the table to a sharepoint list by clicking a button on the excel file.

I am able to import the excel data to sharepoint just fine, but I want the user to be able to "upload" the data to sharepoint by clicking a button. I did find code for that but it appears to be outdated as some functions are not used in Sharepoint anymore.

Does anyone have a solution or an idea how I can create a button in my excel sheet to send the data from several excel files (each with their own button) to a singular sharepoint/excel file (which would be my file).

I have been looking for days and tried powerapps, sql, acces and other approaches but none worked as they should.

Thanks!

Comment: One option is to setup a data connection to the SharePoint list and do an append. See this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/ to setup a data connection, use the Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 driver. Then it should just be a matter of writing a SQL statement.

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions sounds stupid, but I am rather new to anything SQL, SharePoint etc. Basically I would use the connection string provided in your link to connect my Excel files to an SQL Server and then import this to a Sharepoint List?

Comment: Connect your excel sheet to SharePoint with ADO and the connection string referenced. Then write an Append/Insert Into statement to add data from Excel to the Table on SharePoint. I'm assuming you are adding data to a List/Table on SharePoint and you aren't trying to upload the whole spreadsheet to SharePoint, just the data in the document.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. Thank you very much, I'll try it out!